# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia is not working with Android 7 and Ionic 1

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic 1 .
My app is displaying a camera realtime using the Cordova Plugin Camera Preview (9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1))

I am previewing the apk with this command from my desktop :

```
ionic cordova run android
```

My code works **really well** with a **homtom phone using android 5** .

But on my **Android 7 Doggee phone**, it is displaying a **big triangle**, I can't even click on it to take a picture .

[image: big triangle]

This is my code :

```
var videoElement = document.getElementById("video");
var videoSrc = undefined;

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then(getDevices).then(getStream).catch(handleError);

function getDevices(deviceInfos) {
  for (var i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
    var deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
    if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
      videoSrc = deviceInfo.deviceId;
      break;
    }
  }
}

function getStream() {    
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
      deviceId: {
        exact: videoSrc
      }
    }
  }).
  then(gotStream).catch(handleError);
}

function gotStream(stream) {
  videoElement.srcObject = stream;
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.log('Error: ', error);
}
```

And my myproject/platforms/android/app/src/amin/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.ionic.starter" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.cordovaplugincamerapreview.CameraActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraPreviewTheme" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

Then in my \myproject\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\config.xml
I only have this camera feature :

```
 <feature name="CameraPreview">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.cordovaplugincamerapreview.CameraPreview" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
```

This is the error in the phone console

```
Error:  DOMException: Could not start source
```

***EDIT : Finally solved partially :*** 
I have to go into the settings for the application
and give it access to the camera. I thought that I had permission in the
manifest file, but it didn’t seem to grant it for me.

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Use diagnose plugin to check and ask android permission solved my issue.

```
checkpermission()
  {
    this.diagnostic.getPermissionAuthorizationStatus(this.diagnostic.permission.CAMERA)
    .then((status) => {
        switch(status){
            case this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED:
                console.log("Permission granted to use the camera");
                break;
            case this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.NOT_REQUESTED:
                console.log("Permission to use the camera has not been requested yet");
                break;
            case this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED:
                console.log("Permission denied to use the camera - ask again?");
                break;
            case this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED_ALWAYS:
                console.log("Permission permanently denied to use the camera - guess we won't be using it then!");
                break;
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
    });


this.diagnostic.requestRuntimePermission(this.diagnostic.permission.CAMERA)
.then((status) => {
    switch(status){
        case this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED:
            console.log("Permission granted to use the camera");
            break;
        case this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.NOT_REQUESTED:
            console.log("Permission to use the camera has not been requested yet");
            break;
        case this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED:
            console.log("Permission denied to use the camera - ask again?");
            break;
        case this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED_ALWAYS:
            console.log("Permission permanently denied to use the camera - guess we won't be using it then!");
            break;
    }
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
});
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your answer with the code section.